# SAS equivalent of pandas concatenate

Tags: sas

Given *N* datasets - `data1`, `data2`, ..., `dataN` - each containing identical columns, how do I stack them on top of the other in SAS?
In python, I would do the following:

```
combined_data = pd.concat([data1, data2, ..., dataN])
```

What is the SAS syntax for the above command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A method to combine two tables (or more) with the same structure is with the [`SET`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/lestmtsref/p00hxg3x8lwivcn1f0e9axziw57y.htm) statement.

```
data want;
   set data1
       data2
       ...
       dataN
       ;
run;
```

If your datasets all share the same prefix/naming, you could do

```
data want;
   set data:;
run;
```

---

If you only have two tables, you can use the pre-defined SAS procedure [`PROC APPEND`](https://documentation.sas.com/doc/en/pgmsascdc/9.4_3.5/proc/p1bjrbc5esr90on12o8vs7gyv8ue.htm)

```
proc append base=data1 data=data2; run;
```

Please note that:

- With PROC APPEND, you can only append two tables while with SET you can append two or more.
- PROC APPEND is faster than SET statement because it only reads in the data set being appended.

Comment: the `set data:` is just what I needed.  I have an unknown number of datasets each with identical prefixes.